# Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 cannot type crypt password in & other weird issues on fresh install

Tags: drivers, 17.04, ubuntu-gnome, cryptsetup

I've installed Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 with full disk encryption using the LVM option, everything went fine until I rebooted and it asked me to type in my crypt password on the splash screen, I go to type on the keyboard and no input at all, I can press Ctrl + Alt F1 or F2 but that just takes me to a black screen and I cannot get back from there.

The only way for me to boot into Ubuntu Gnome is hard resetting my PC and use recovery mode which allows me to type in my crypt password from the text based console, however my keyboard is sometimes not picked up there either, so I have to keep rebooting into recovery mode until my keyboard loads...

After using recovery mode and typing in my crypt password, I can get into Ubuntu Gnome... However, sometimes on logging in to my user I will get a blank/ grey screen with just a mouse cursor; no keyboard input or anything else, the only way to solve that is to reboot again and hope it does not happen.

I know you can use no splash to get around the no input on the splash screen for crypt setup, but I really dislike that way of booting up, I wanna see and use the splash screen, not the console at the start, so using no splash is not a solution for me, I've also had this issue on the same computer with other distros like KDE Neon and elementary which all come from Ubuntu...

I've updated my install and GPU drivers, I'm running the kernel which comes with Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 which is 4.10 and Im using Gnome 3.24.2

Here is my output from `lshw -short` to show my hardware setup:

```
H/W path                 Device     Class          Description
==============================================================
                                    system         Z170X-Gaming 7 (Default strin
/0                                  bus            Z170X-Gaming 7
/0/0                                memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/3d                               memory         32GiB System Memory
/0/3d/0                             memory         Project-Id-Version: lshwRepor
/0/3d/1                             memory         16GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3
/0/3d/2                             memory         Project-Id-Version: lshwRepor
/0/3d/3                             memory         16GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 3
/0/43                               memory         256KiB L1 cache
/0/44                               memory         1MiB L2 cache
/0/45                               memory         8MiB L3 cache
/0/46                               processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CP
/0/100                              bridge         Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Regi
/0/100/1                            bridge         Skylake PCIe Controller (x16)
/0/100/1/0                          display        GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080]
/0/100/1/0.1                        multimedia     GP104 High Definition Audio C
/0/100/14                           bus            Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI 
/0/100/14/0              usb1       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0/1                       bus            USB hub
/0/100/14/0/2                       input          Razer Mamba Tournament Editio
/0/100/14/0/4            scsi8      storage        v195b
/0/100/14/0/4/0.0.0      /dev/sdb   disk           32GB v195b
/0/100/14/0/4/0.0.0/0    /dev/sdb   disk           32GB 
/0/100/14/0/4/0.0.0/0/1  /dev/sdb1  volume         29GiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100/14/0/5                       input          Corsair STRAFE RGB Gaming Key
/0/100/14/0/8                       input          USB Receiver
/0/100/14/0/a                       generic        H115i
/0/100/14/1              usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/1/1                       bus            USB hub
/0/100/16                           communication  Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1
/0/100/17                           storage        Sunrise Point-H SATA controll
/0/100/1b                           bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Root Port
/0/100/1b.2                         bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Root Port
/0/100/1b.3                         bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Root Port
/0/100/1b.3/0                       storage        ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller
/0/100/1c                           bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Express R
/0/100/1c.1                         bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Express R
/0/100/1c.2                         bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Express R
/0/100/1c.2/0            enp7s0     network        Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet
/0/100/1c.4                         bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Express R
/0/100/1c.4/0                       bridge         DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge 
/0/100/1c.4/0/0                     bridge         DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge 
/0/100/1c.4/0/1                     bridge         DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge 
/0/100/1c.4/0/2                     bridge         DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge 
/0/100/1c.4/0/2/0                   bus            DSL6540 USB 3.1 Controller [A
/0/100/1c.4/0/2/0/0      usb3       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1c.4/0/2/0/1      usb4       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1c.4/0/4                     bridge         DSL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge 
/0/100/1d                           bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Express R
/0/100/1d.4                         bridge         Sunrise Point-H PCI Express R
/0/100/1d.4/0                       storage        NVMe SSD Controller SM951/PM9
/0/100/1f                           bridge         Sunrise Point-H LPC Controlle
/0/100/1f.2                         memory         Memory controller
/0/100/1f.3                         multimedia     Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
/0/100/1f.4                         bus            Sunrise Point-H SMBus
/0/100/1f.6              enp0s31f6  network        Ethernet Connection (2) I219-
/0/1                     scsi5      storage        
/0/1/0.0.0               /dev/sda   disk           1TB ST1000DM003-1SB1
/0/1/0.0.0/1             /dev/sda1  volume         931GiB Windows NTFS volume
/1                                  power          To Be Filled By O.E.M.
```